# Silk Test 15.5 Exporting Text to Excel Using Active data

Tags: excel, silktest

Using SilkTest with a visual test and active data I am using the GetText function/Action to grab text on a web app but unfortunately this text is a dynamic object and changes everytime this script is ran.

The GetText is obviously not working because this object and text value is dynamic and whenever the locator is stored it will not be same as the next document number value.

Just to provide additional information: I am trying to grab a unique document number, exporting it to excel using active data and then will later open the document in a later part of the scenario.

Thanks for any insight or guidance!

Comment: Thanks! Just an FYI for others, I also had to use that dynamic text, export to excel, create an expression with some local variables to wrap around the dynamic data to make a locator string to be used in a later part of the flow. Also, the GetText method did not work but TextCapture did. Thanks again for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give an example of the locator, remember that you can use wild card characters in the locator string to cater for situations where the properties it uses are dynamic.  Also, have you tried using different properties which may be more stable.